# Overload enum abstract method

Tags: java, enums, overloading, overriding

Is it possible to overload Enum abstract method?

I have tried this in my code with no effect.
Presented class

```
public class Test {
    public void test(String string){
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public void test(Object object){
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new Object();
        test.test(object);
        test.test("what if?");
    }
}
```

gives expected result of

```
Test1
what if?
```

while enum

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1{
        public void test(String string){
            System.out.println(string);
        }

        public void test(Object object){
            System.out.println("Test1");
        }
    },
    TEST2{
        public void test(Object object){
            System.out.println("Test2");
        }
    };

    public abstract void test(Object object);
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = new Object();
        TestEnum.TEST1.test("what if?");
        TestEnum.TEST1.test(object);
    }
}
```

returns

```
Test1
Test1
```

Is it even possible to overload Enum methods or am I doing something wrong? Or maybe should I check for type inside of overriden method and then act accordingly? But then I remove switch statement only to introduce another switch statement.

Comment: This isn't something about enums specifically.  This is that _in general_ which method is called is decided at compile time based on the _type_ of the object, not the specific object.  If you want anything like this -- whether with enums, or any other type -- you'll have to check the type explicitly at runtime with `instanceof`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Or by using explicit double dispatch

Comment: The thing about enums is that values with bodies are implemented as anonymous subclasses of `TestEnum`; so they look like `TestEnum TEST1 = new TestEnum() { /* body */ }`. So, whilst the concrete class of `TEST1` is, say `TestEnum$1`, the reference is of type `TestEnum`, so your code can only access methods defined on `TestEnum`.

Comment: @AndyTurner's got it.

Comment: By the way, use `@Override` on your overridden methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing about enums is that values with bodies are implemented as anonymous subclasses of `TestEnum`; so they look like this:

```
final TestEnum TEST1 = new TestEnum() { /* body */ };
```

Whilst the concrete class of `TEST1` is, say `TestEnum$1` (or whatever name the compiler decides to give it), the reference is of type `TestEnum`, so any code outside the body of `TEST1` can only access methods defined on `TestEnum`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible, you are somehow not implementing that in a particular way....

you should 
define an interface with the methods you want to override

```
interface Ifoo {
    public void test(Object object);

    public void test(String object);
}
```

then remove the abstract method of the enum and make the enum implement that interface, but override those methods in every constant of the enumerator...

```
enum TestEnum implements Ifoo {
    TEST1 {
    @Override
    public void test(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    @Override
    public void test(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }
    },
    TEST2 {
    @Override
    public void test(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    @Override
    public void test(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    };
}
```

finally implement it like>

```
Object object = new Object();
TestEnum.TEST1.test("what if?");
TestEnum.TEST1.test(object);
TestEnum.TEST2.test("why not?");
TestEnum.TEST2.test(object);
```

your result should looks like:

> what if?
>
> Test1
>
> why not?
>
> Test2

Comment: The interface isn't really necessary, it would've worked without it. However, I think OP was trying to overload the method only for specific enum values.

Comment: ohhh.... now I see the question in a different way.... thanks for the comment @radoh

Comment: The interface approach is overkill unless you need to refer to the enum by a supertype. Interfaces are to establish types, which is unlikely to be necessary here. The abstract method approach within the enum itself is pretty much all you'll ever need.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing an example with a class and then you are showing an example with an enum. I believe you think these examples are equivalent, however, they are completely different each other.

For the example of your class to be equivalent to the example of your enum, you should modify your `Test` class so that it extends an abstract `AbstractTest` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    public abstract void test(Object object);
}

public class Test extends AbstractTest {

    public void test(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    @Override
    public void test(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }
}
```

Now, if you try the same lines you've tried in your first `main`:

```
AbstractTest test = new Test();
Object object = new Object();
test.test(object);
test.test("what if?");
```

You'll notice that the output has now become:

```
Test1
Test1
```

Which is something to be expected, because Java doesn't provide a feature called [*dynamic dispatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). Informally, dynamic dispatch means that the overloaded method to be executed is decided at runtime, based on the polymorphic types of the parameters. Instead, Java decides the method to be executed at compilation time, based on the *declared* type of the object whose method is to be invoked (in this case `AbstractTest`).

With enums, this is exactly what happens. All the elements of the enum (`TEST1` and `TEST2` in your example) belong to the type of the enum (`TestEnum` in your case), so the compiler always goes for the method that is declared as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get twice "Test1" is because you have declared only this method
`public abstract void test(Object object);`
Precisely, this method will "catch" all calls whit any type of parameter. String extends Object (indirectly), so String is Object and this method we be called.
In other words, method wich receives parameter String will be hidden by the method which receives parameter Object.

The solution is to add next method declaration in enum
`public abstract void test(String string);`
You will have to add the implementation of this method to `TEST2` constant.

Code

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1 {
        public void test(String string) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

        public void test(Object object) {
            System.out.println("Test1");
        }
    },
    TEST2 {
        public void test(Object object) {
            System.out.println("Test2");
        }

        @Override
        public void test(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    public abstract void test(Object object);

    public abstract void test(String string);
}
```

This code gives output

```
what if?
Test1
```